# difference between yum, dnf and pip

Tags: fedora, package-management

I found that there's several ways to install packages in fedora, using pip,  yum or dnf. is there more? what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) is a python package manager.  It will only install python modules/packages.

yum is the old Fedora/RedHat installation tool that installs RPMs and does dependency resolution for you.

[dnf](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/DNF) is a new replacement for yum

As for others, if you're counting `pip` then sure, there's also perl's CPAN stuff, gems for ruby, npm for JavaScript.  Surely many many others.

Comment: just 2c https://xkcd.com/927/ (that's relevant for pip, npm, gem and other things)

Comment: @MikhailKrutov also relevant: http://xkcd.com/1654/